# Ищу документацию по Angular 2 JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, документация, angular2

Я ищу документацию по Angular 2 JavaScript (не TypeScript).
Есть ли у кого под рукой такой ресурс? Прошу поделится.

Comment: Не холивара ради - но многое усложняете использованием js, не зря они основным TypeScript выбрали.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian Хотите сказать стоит использовать TypeScript + JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

[Курс по Angular2](https://www.codeschool.com/courses/accelerating-through-angular-2)

[Документация по Angular2](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/index.html)

Comment: Ваша вторая ссылка на TypeScript((

Comment: @HakobShaghikyan На JavaScript, приглядитесь повнимательнее. UPD Хотя похоже документация написана в расчете на TypeScript (переменные с типами), но если перейти на Quick Start то там будет именно версия для js

Comment: @Alexandr Я уже установил Angular 2, всё нормально работает, только вот например мне нужна информация про $http я никак не могу её найти.Мне нужны документации про функции Angular 2.

Comment: @HakobShaghikyan Вот это? https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/http/index/Http-class.html

Просто не смотрите на типизацию (xxx: string) и будет Javascript

Comment: @Alexandr Ну там чуть внизу есть пример а он на TypeScript.Но стоит ли использовать TypeScript + JavaScript?.

Comment: @HakobShaghikyan Да, примеры все на TypeScript, придется немного додумывать как это будет выглядеть в чистом js. Фундаментальных отличий-то нет.

Comment: @Alexandr А что насчёт TypeScript + JavaScript?) Стоит их вместе использовать?

Comment: @HakobShaghikyan Тут на ваше усмотрение. Как удобнее. Если использовать все возможности ES6 все равно придется компилировать js для старых браузеров. В этом случае, наверное, лучше все же чистый TypeScript использовать, на нем писать под angular2 будет гораздо удобнее

Comment: @Alexandr Angular 2 Идёт только на серверах Node JS да?

Comment: @HakobShaghikyan Это же клиентская библиотека, идет на любых веб-серверах если правильно приготовить (Пу сути скомпилировать ts в js и правильно настроить SystemJs)

Comment: @Alexandr Где можно найти документацию или просто пример использования Angular 2 на простом веб-сервере?

Comment: @HakobShaghikyan если у вас нормально работает в том окружении которое описано в туториале (nodejs + lite-server), то просто можно скопировать всю папку с исходниками в папку со статикой веб-сервера и все должно заработать. При этом конечно много лишнего скопируется, но для проверки работоспособности этого достаточно.

Comment: @Alexandr Я должен подключится консолью к этой директории и включить сервер "npm start" вот тогда всё работает а без этого никак, и вот на сервере как то хочется без этого обойтись, возможно это сделать или нет?)

Comment: npm start включает компиляцию ts файлов и запускает локальный веб-сервер (lite-server) чтобы был хоть какой-то веб-сервер. По умолчанию этот сервер стартует на 3000 порту. Если у вас есть другой веб-сервер и скомпилированные файлы то nodejs (и npm) не нужен.

Answer (score 1):

Нет поверьте.Но можно сделать так,посмотреть чуть видео чтоб иметь представление,и понять что **Ангуляр 2** и **Ангуляр 1** совсем разные подходы.
Вот например [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=63SkXao3tsA) ,парень грамотно объясняет.
Ну или поискать что то в этом вроде.

> А затем обязательно прочитать документацию к сожалению на английском.

Я тоже хреново понимал в своё время английский, и поступил именно так.

Удачи !